# Ways to Download Videos and Store in SD Card in Android

Tags: android-download-manager

I have a video file from Service in .MP4 format and I want to allow the user to be able to download the video to their SD card(Storing in App Folder) and view that,
I used **DownloadManger** For that one,after that I came to know that for using that we should have minimum version as **"11"**,But For My App,Minimum Version is **"8"**..How to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no compatibility for `DownloadManager` for android 8.
The only alternative is to create your own downloader for android 8 devices.

[this stackoverflow answer is a good example to follow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3028660/2027232).